# Помогите пожалуйста. Не понимаю как записать факториал

Tags: c++

```
0 < |x| < 1
Допустим x = 0.66
k = 0 

делимое я расписал вот так - pow(x, 2k)
а вот делитель я хз как расписать. Я пробовал факториал закодить 
через функцию, но 
ничего не получилось. Помогите пожалуйста реализовать (2k)!
```

[image: само задание]

Comment: `(2k)! = 1*2*3*...*(2k-1)*2k` Впрочем, считать факториал для каждого члена не имеет смысла, ст*о*ит рассмотреть отношение `a_{k+1}/a_k` и разобраться как считать очередной член исходя из предыдущего...

Answer (score 3):

А что тут понимать? Пусть `t(k)` - k-й член ряда (выражение под суммой):

```
t(k) = x^(2k) / (2k)!
```

Здесь `^` - возведение в степень. Тогда (k+1)-й член ряда:

```
t(k+1) = x^(2(k+1)) / (2(k+1))! 
       = x^(2k+2) / (2k+2)! 
       = x^(2k) * x^2 / [(2k)!(2k+1)(2k+2)] 
       = t(k) * x^2 / [(2k+1)(2k+2)]
```

0-й член ряда:

```
t(0) = x^(2*0) / (2*0)! = 1
```

Отсюда можем построить код:

```
double get_sum(double x, double epsilon, uint64_t max_count)
{
    double s = 1;
    double t = 1;
    double x2 = x*x;

    for (uint64_t k = 0; (k < max_count) && (abs(t) > epsilon); ++k)
    {
        uint64_t k2 = k + k + 1;
        t*= x2/k2/(k2+1);
        s+= t;
    }

    return s;
}
```

Т.е., явно возводить в степень и считать факториал в каждом цикле не нужно и не правильно - это очень медленно. Подобные ряды считаются на основе реккурентного соотношения выражения под суммой.